# Is it possible to change the Date format for UGC Comment?

Tags: ugc

I want to change the format of date in comment published. The default format is like **'3/29/2014 2:43:30 AM'** and I want to change it (for example MMMM dd, yyyy  HH:MM:SS AM).

I use this **DWT** code:

```
<p class="author"><tcdl:ContextVariable var="ugcComment.user.name"/></p>
<p class="date"><tcdl:ContextVariable var='ugcComment.LastModifiedDate'/></p>
```

Is there a method to change the format date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give format to the date fields in UGC we usually use the following code using javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var date = "<tcdl:ContextVariable var="ugcComment.creationDate"/>";
    var d = new Date(date.replace(/CES?T/,"    "));
    var curr_date = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var curr_month = ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var curr_hh = d.getHours();
    var curr_mm = d.getMinutes();
    document.write("<p class=\"fecha\">" + curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year + " " + curr_hh +":"+ curr_mm +"</p>");
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer server-side  solution, you could do as following (in .net):

```
<% DateTime commentCreateionDate = (DateTime) Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.Web.UI.When.EvaluateVariable("ugcComment.CreationDate", HttpContext.Current); %>    
// add your desired format
<% =commentCreateionDate.ToString("dd MM yyy") %>
```